# Setup Sharepoint Foundation 2013 https connection in Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: https, sharepoint-2013, foundation, tfs-2015, fqdn

I set up a single Server installation of TFS 2015
SQL Server+Sharepoint Foundation 2013+TFS 2015 on one machine.
The Server has multiple IPs and each installation is listening on an different IP.

Sharepoint uses to IPs one for the normal SP-Sites and one for Central Administration. All IPs have an FQDN registered. The Sharepoint sites (Sharepoint - 80 and Central Administration) are configured to use HTTPS only and use the FQDNs. I could not get the SharePoint Web Services to run HTTPS only so I stick with default settings.

I also disabled the disabled the loopback check for the FQDNs so that the FQDN can be used on the same server. When running the TFS Configuration Wizard all went fine till the SharePoint settings. TFS keeps telling me that he cannot access the SharePoint websites or Central Administration. The urls are working with a browser from the same machine an I am out of ideas why TFS can't connect to SharePoint using the FQDNs. Using the machine name is not an option since "SharePoint - 80" and "Central Administration" running on the same port just different IPs.

Are there any settings I could try to make things work?

Comment: Have you check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872(v=vs.120).aspx?

Comment: Yes I did. So far no luck. Could the problem be that the FQDNs are in other domain than the Server. Server: servername.dom1.com FQDNs: FQ.dom2.com. On the other calling sharepoint with the browser from the same machine and from others is working just fine.

Comment: @ErichBauer, 1). Do not configure 'SharePoint' and 'Central Administration' with the same port. 2). Why you set up multiple IPs with different FQDNs on the same machine?

Comment: @Vicky ad 2) Because it can happen that the parts got installed on different machines during the lifetime of the server using different IPs from the start has proven to make moving to other machines much less painful in the past.

Comment: @ErichBauer, firstly I don't think configuring one machine with multiple IPs is a good idea when set up TFS server, you can set up VMs and install TFS and SharePoint on different VM. Secondly, please go to Alternate Access Mappings to have a check on Public URL of the Central Administration website, and use the Public URL to configure with TFS.